# [embed]Using Wordpress 5.5.1 there is no embed option after the video is uploaded

Tags: embed

I have looked at many posts explaining how to embed a video mp4 from my computer to Wordpress and they invariably show a box with the option to embed the video. In my Wordpress version 5.5.1 this never shows. All I am left with is a link which when clicked downloads the video in extreme bottom left of screen withe the necessity to click "Open"  or "Open when finished". Why am I not seeing the option to embed?

Answer (score 0):

Can use html5 for video playing embed or Manually enter embed code.

[How to Embed a Video to your WordPress Post](https://horje.com/tips/58611)

Or use directly

```
 <video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```